# ¿Cómo establecer el mismo tamaño para varias imágenes con CSS?

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo una página web donde se muestran varias imágenes dependiendo la petición que le corresponda.

Al mostrar las imágenes le establezco `width` y `height`, me muestra todas las imágenes del mismo tamaño.

Todo esta correcto hasta aquí, pero agregué un efecto con CSS, donde al pasar el ratón se agranda la imagen.

En este caso sí se agranda, pero algunas me muestran más pequeñas otras más grandes. Todo esto lo realicé poniendo una clase a la imagen.

Éste es mi CSS:

```
.imgcec{
position: relative;
left: 20px;
transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}
.imgcec:hover {
  position:relative;
  top:-120px;
  left:-243px;
  width:457px;
  height:260px;
  display:block;
  z-index:999;
}
.imgcec:hover {
transform: scale(1.7);
}
```

Cualquier sugerencia en cómo poder solucionar el tamaño se los agradecería. Ya coloqué `width` y `height` al evento `hover`, pero no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Todas las imagen tienen la misma resolución nativa?

Comment: No amigo, es por eso?

Comment: No amigo, es por eso? pero no entiendo por que al no tener el hover se muestran las imágenes del mismo tamaño.

Comment: Es para reproducir el problema. Lo ideal es que compartieras un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en el que se viera el problema que estás sufriendo, haciendo uso de imágenes públicas si no deseas usar las tuyas para así facilitarnos la tarea de identificar el problema.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás teniendo es que las imágenes tienen un tamaño libre por defecto, por lo que al llegar el evento `hover` éstas tratan de cambiar al estilo que le has fijado que es:

```
.imgcec:hover {
  position:relative;
  top:-120px;
  left:-243px;
  width:457px;
  height:260px;
  display:block;
  z-index:999;
}
.imgcec:hover {
transform: scale(1.7);
}
```

Por lo que aquellas imágenes que sea más grandes de 457 x 1.7 de ancho y 457 x 1.7 de ancho verán su tamaño reducido en vez de ampliado.

Visto el problema, lo que necesitas es fijar el tamaño de la imagen ANTES de que pase el cursor sobre la imagen y, posteriormente, aplicar únicamente la transformación en el selector `:hover`.

De esta manera solo se cambiará la transformación `scale(1.7)` al pasar el cursor por encima de la imagen, y no las propiedades de tamaño, posición, etc que provocaban el comportamiento tan extraño que sufrías:

```css
.imgcec {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  position: relative;
  top: -120px;
  left: -243px;
  width: 457px;
  height: 260px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  /* Para ver la transformación mejor */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.imgcec:hover {
  transform: scale(1.7);
}

/* Ajusto los márgenes para que se vean las imágenes */
body {
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-top: 125px;
}
```

```html
<img class="imgcec" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Letter_A.svg/1024px-Letter_A.svg.png" />
<img class="imgcec" src="https://conceptodefinicion.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/letras-1.jpg" />
<img class="imgcec" src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEFpzgDqdJzpw/company-logo_200_200/0/1626070433143?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=WErN7se_HsKBOYLJq-fVZyhMwqzoB1h0fwkEDpx84MQ" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Aún sin ver el HTML (que ayudaría a asegurar la solución) veo que tienes la clase imgcec repetida y que no das un tamaño a las imágenes. Lo que yo haría es:

```
.imgcec{
position: relative;
left: 0px;
  width:228px;
  height:130px;
  transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s; /* Animation */
}
.imgcec:hover {
  width:456px;
  height:260px;
  display:block;
  z-index:999;
}
```

La primera regla es la imagen normal donde le doy un **tamaño fijo**, si no quieres deformaciones procura que las imágenes tengan la misma proporción alto/ancho.
También la la primera regla le pongo al transición al alto y ancho.
La segunda regla simplemente las amplía hasta el tamaño final que quieras.

Comment: Más o menos lo que le propuse yo (pero yo mantuve la transformación, tú lo has cambiado por un cambio de tamaño), pero para que te funcione correctamente te falta agregar `height` en `transition`. Por ejemplo, `transition: width 2s, height 2s;`.

Comment: Gracias, cierto, se me pasó el segundo efecto y la duración también dejé la de prueba. Realmente el scale también debiera funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: La ventaja es que `scale` pone como origen del efecto de agrandamiento el centro de la imagen, provocando que aparentemente la imagen crezca por igual por todos sus lados. En tu caso la imagen se agranda expandiéndose solo hacia abajo y hacia la derecha, manteniendo los bordes superiores e izquierdo estáticos, dando una impresión muy diferente a la que busca el OP.